# Confusing Positioning Issues

Tags: php, html, css, drupal

**FOR CHORME AND FIREFOX ONLY**

Consider the following link http://indivar.biz/deva/node/41 and then hover the tab "TRAINING PROGRAMMES", it will open the sub menus. The opened sub menus open below the "UPCOMING PROGRAMMES", the heading in below purple box. And the need is to open above the purple box properly.

So, can you please let me know, how can this issue will resolved. The sub menus working fine on Home page, but on internal pages.

THANKS
BALKAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS.

```
#background-bg {
  {
   position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
  }
#content > .wrapper {
  {
   position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
  }
```

Though it is advisable to not use ID for styling but you go along with this patch. It won't be a problem.

Comment: Why isnt it advisable to use an id for styling?

Comment: Styles written using CSS ID selectors are not reusable. Also the code becomes less maintainable. You can read this article for more insight. http://oli.jp/2011/ids/

Comment: I have to disagree, An ID style is perfectly valid for a unique non repeating element.

Comment: I never questioned the validity. I just said that it is advisable.

Comment: I agree that it wont be advisable to use ID very commonly as CSS selector. Just check this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/mknut/7/) where I have applied color to <span>; once using id selector and once using specific class selector. The css defined using ID selector over-rides styles defined using class selector for some reason which may not cause problem with 100 lines of css but may cause problem when you have a common css of over 1000 lines for every page of your website.

Answer (score 0):

on this class .node-type-page #background-bg z-index is 0, increase it to 1 or more, problem will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

wrapere position relative and z-index as like this

```
#content  >  .wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 960px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Azad, your code works Well !!